# iPad login fails in private browsing mode

Tags: support, login, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safari  5.1.2 log in doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123116/safari-5-1-2-log-in-doesnt-work)

How do I login into Stack Overflow from iPad?

I go to the login page but when I click on log in on Google, Facebook etc the JavaScript does not work.

Only way that seems to work is OpenID (as this renders the login input eg login name)

**Updated**

I recieve javascript error after switching debug console:
**Javascript:Error**
undefined
QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota

**Update 2**
This only happens when "Private Browsing" is turned on:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which iOS version?

Comment: @Kevin: I am using IOS 5.0.1 on ipad 1

Comment: This only happens when Private Browsing is turned on, I reproduced on iPad 2 IOS 5.0.1

Comment: I've had this work on iPad 2 (forget which browser though) so it sounds like it's a iPad private browsing thing not an iPad thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine on my iPhone, and iPad 2.
Try enabling the debug console (`Settings > Safari > Advanced > Debug Console`)

Might give you feedback on error that's coming up (if any)

Comment: Okay, will have a look on this tonight I am using IPAD 1

Comment: sorry for the late accept