# Safari  5.1.2 log in doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, safari

Just had the issue yesterday, that I could not log in via Safari browser.
Page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
Safari 5.1.2.

I tried to log in via stack exchange and got following error:

```
QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.
openid-jquery.js:7
```

Comment: I don't think that's Safari related necessarily - it's because the scripts don't gracefully handle an add-to-local-storage failure. But maybe it's easiest to reproduce in Safari. (BTW have you deliberately set a very low local storage limit, or is that default behaviour? And is this Safari on Windows or Mac? I know they ought to be the same but I've seen rendering bugs on Windows but not Mac.)

Comment: it is safari on mac. i just checked safari under windows, there it works... safari is default behaviour...
it was just driving me crazy two days ago because i was started to think i m too stupid to log in :D ok, maybe it s only a bug at my machine. just wanted to report! thanks for tips

Comment: No, it is something that should be fixed: they need to catch  exceptions from `window.localStorage.setItem()` and probably just ignore them. (Or remember the failure and don't try to do it again, but ignore is easiest.)

Comment: It works for me with Safari 5.1.3. I tried logging out, and in, on this very site, and I didn't get any error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, Apple does something a little funny in privacy mode here...instead of saying "we don't support `window.localStorage`", it just throws an error when you try to call `setItem` on it.  IMO this is bad behavior, but it's how Safari (on the iPad at least) works.

We'll trap and ignore that error just not remembering what you logged in with in these cases after the next build.