# Cannot login while in private browsing mode on iPad 2

Tags: support, login

I understand that this issue was addressed last year here [Safari  5.1.2 log in doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123116/safari-5-1-2-log-in-doesnt-work)

However, while in private browsing mode, I cannot login to Stackoverflow using Google as my OpenID provider. I am already logged in but Safari does not redirect. I am using iOS 6.0.1.